# React Native asyncstorage to save the style of a button

Tags: react-native

I have two buttons that i would like to save the style in the asyncstorage.
At the moment they are saved in the state like this:

```
 state = {
  itemOne:styles.button,
  itemTwo:styles.button,
}
```

And depending on the value the styles change

```
  if (value) {
                switch (value) {
                    case "Low":
                        this.setState({itemOne: styles.styleOne});
                        break;
                    case "Moderate":
                        this.setState({itemOne: styles.styleTwo});
                        break;

                }
            }
```

And the button in the view looks like this

```
 <Button
                        style={this.state.itemOne}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.popupDialog.show();
                        }}
                    >
```

I m using AsyncStorage to save the state but its coming up with this error

```
 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `0` supplied to `View`.
Bad object: {
  "0": "6",
  "1": "9",
  "opacity": 1
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You can save object with JSON serialize/deserialize. How did you store style object on AsyncStorage? Can you add your AsyncStorage code? If you get and set like this. It will be fixed

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem("myStyle", JSON.stringify(style)); //for set
```

and

```
var style = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("myStyle"));
```